# Matlab calculate delta of a tall column (current timestamp - previous timestamp)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have absolutely no idea on how to calculate the difference between previous and current value of a tall array column.

What I try to do:
I have a tall array column with a timestamp. Now to make different calculations I want also a tall array column with the delta timestamp (current timestamp - previous timestamp).

As it is not possible to do this in a loop, I have no idea on how to do this.

Can somebody assist me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [`diff`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)

Assuming you're using the word "tall" in its technical sense (i.e. [tall arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tall.tall.html)) then `diff` is in the [function list](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/referencelist.html?type=function&capability=tall) for compatable out-of-memory functions for use with `tall` data.